# mySQL AND memcached for PHP sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, session, memcached

For a high traffic web site we are planning to scale up to use 2 web servers in a HA setup.

One issue we will need to tackle is the management of PHP sessions.

The obvious answer is to move session handling to the DB which is easy and example code is widely available ton the internet.

On the other hand we are aware of the benefits of memcached but once a memcached node fails, users on that node will lose their session.

So we are thinking of implementing a setup where sessions are handled in memcached by default but also written in the DB. When we get a memcached MISS we would try to also retrieve it from the DB.

Does the above make sense and are there any implementation examples you are aware of?

thanks in advance

Comment: why just don't use a PHP cloud? that would save you 60% of work

Comment: I suggest you [read this question from serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/questions/164350/can-a-pool-of-memcache-daemons-be-used-to-share-sessions-more-efficiently).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I refer you to Dormando's oft-cited explanation of [how to store sessions in MySQL with memcached caching](http://dormando.me/articles/memcached_sessions/). The [original LiveJournal post](http://dormando.livejournal.com/495593.html) is more wordy but more thoroughly explains why storing sessions in memcached only is a bad idea.

In short:

- Read session data from memcached first, look in MySQL on a cache miss.
- Write session data to memcached on every update.
- Only write to MySQL if cache data hasn't been synced for 120 seconds or so.
- Run a periodic script that checks MySQL for expired sessions. For every expired session, update from memcached and only expire the ones that are truly expired.

Comment: Create additional IO operations and DB-queries to handle sessions it's stupid idea. I have experience of using Memcache and APC for sessions, and MySQL too. Without MySQL sessions works 10-20 times faster.

Comment: I have experience developing systems for which high reliability is a requirement and dropped sessions get you yelled at. Using a volatile cache as the only persistent store for any data that you care about is asking for trouble.

Comment: @squirrel, if system becomes non-stable just because session was dropped - it's bad designed system. Session can be dropped (or lost) by user, by thousands of reasons. Session IS volatile thing.

Comment: @OZ_, it's more about the _perception_ of instability. Users don't like being logged out mid-session because a memcached node went offline. Why even bother setting up a HA cluster if you're just going to store sessions in memcached and hope for the best? It's not "10-20 times faster" than a properly designed memcached+MySQL setup and the MySQL store gets you the best of both worlds, speed with reliability.

Comment: @squirrel, and again, how often memcache-node falls? once per month? So you want to reduce total performance just because once per month memcache-node may fall? I prefer to give users higher availability (higher speed of pages loading), than spent their time and server's performance to prevent theoretical losing of sessions. Sessions it's not billing system, it's not critical data. And, as I wrote already in my answer, if you just want more reliability even in sessions, you can try to use Redis as existing solution for periodic dumping data from memory to disk.

Comment: @OZ_, the question was about a high-availability configuration. I assume that means a node going offline should have no visible effect on the system. Even when no memcached node goes offline you can still lose session data if the cache is being over-utilized. Whether the persistent storage is MySQL or Redis doesn't matter much; the memcached developers and other HA developers out there all recommend using memcached for caching only, not for storage.

Comment: @squirrel, `MySQL or Redis doesn't matter much` - heh, it really does matter, it's absolutely different storages.

Comment: @OZ_, it doesn't matter to the original question ("does it make sense to write sessions to persistent storage and cache them in memcached?") or to my answer ("yes that makes sense, here's an example").

Comment: @squirrel, you just want to believe in that. MySQL+Memcached+Cron it's old spike-nail, Redis is good modern solution.

Comment: @squirrel many thanks. You summarized very well what we are trying to do. In the mean time I found this example code as well: http://pureform.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/memcache-mysql-php-session-handler/  we ll give it a try!

Comment: @OZ_ thanks for your comments. sessions in memcached can be lost for many reasons, not only crashes. Think a cloud based setup where you scale up and down depending on traffic patterns during the day where memcached instances are created and then destroyed. Or when memcached allocated memory gets full and deletes some of the records. We want best of both worlds really! Redis looks cool by the way. I need to read more about it!

Comment: @webgr, Redis can be used at few servers to. Anyway, looks like you want to use only MySQL and Memcache and you are looking not for answer, but for `yes, you are right`. Problem not in Memcache, but you don't want to listen it.

Comment: Maybe you should try to understand the context and the business requirements a bit better. Memcache alone is a no-no for our sessions. We simply do not want to introduce single points of failure for our session variables! Memcache (as a cache) with a persistent storage on the back end is a good fit tor our requirements and we already have the infrastructure up and running. It seems Redis with Append-only files could achieve something similar.

Comment: Link in answer is down here is a [similar link](http://orig.keboola.com/blog/php-sessions-with-memcached-and-a-database-session-in-the-cloud-done-right/)

Answer (score 1):

Sessions it's a temporary thing, there is nothing to worry about if once per month memcache-server will fail and truncate sessions. I'm sure you can use just memcache for sessions, without replication in DB.

But if you still want to dump sessions to disk, as existing solution you can use [**Redis**](http://redis.io/topics/introduction):

> *Redis works with an in-memory dataset.
>   Depending on your use case, you can
>   persist it either by dumping the
>   dataset to disk*

...

> *Redis also supports trivial-to-setup master-slave replication, with very
>   fast non-blocking first
>   synchronization, auto-reconnection on
>   net split and so forth.*